# header custom background color with mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

i'm new to Jquery mobile and i want to change background css of the header of Jquery mobile header.
any help?

```
<div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    </div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: Please be clear on the question.

Comment: What part of header you want to change?

Comment: change css background of the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change the background color of header use code like this

```
.ui-header{
background: red;
```

}

the link code is 
[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/qF6aF/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<div data-role="header" id="my_header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

In your css:

#my_header .ui_header { background-color: #ccc }